# Stuck with the Implementation of Deep learning model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I intend to implement the deep learning model depicted in the image below.

[image]

The image depicts two models in the Training phase. The output of 1ST Model (Blue rectangle) should be the input of 2ND Model (Red rectangle) (yellow rectangle). Rest, each model will train on its own gradients relative to its own losses. Note that the gradients of the second model will not pass through to the first model.

And in Testing, I want to test samples only on the second model (yellow rectangle).

How can this be implemented in TensorFlow Keras? Any examples, suggestions, or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to train these side-by-side? Alternating training steps? Simulatanously? Train-the-first-and-once-it's-trained-then-train-the-other? There isn't enough context to try and answer the question...

Comment: Maybe provide some code to show what you have tried otherwise your question might be closed.

Comment: @ShlomiF Thank you for the comment. I want to train side-by-side.

Comment: @AloneTogether I don't have the code right now. I am planning to implement it but do not have the idea how I should handle these two model with their losses. That's why asking.

Comment: Start reading here: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I know the basic implementation. But the model given in above image is not straight forward. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: It is straightforward, I suggest that you read the link carefully :) its just a model with some sub-models and two outputs (with their own gradients).

Comment: Based on your requirements "the gradients of the second model will not pass through to the first model", I think you simply have two decoupled models that can be built and trained independently. Now, since your second model gets the output of the first one as its input, you need to first train the first model, and then use its output to train the second model.